# Angular2 + imgcache unsafe URL

Tags: cordova, caching, angular, ionic2, cordova-3

I am using imgcache to cache images for a cordova app and then display the cached image if the image is already cached.

After I get the cached URL, when I try to set the img src property, I get the following error.

> unsafe:filesystem:http://localhost:8100/temporary/imgcache/108a8c16ec8d04c1d104240c56b97843068a6e08.jpg
>
> ```
> net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
> ```

I tried calling the dom.bypassSecurityTrustUrl, to mark the URL safe, but I still get the error.

```
ImgCache.cacheFile(this.image, (cachedFile: string) => {
    console.log(this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(cachedFile));
        this.src = cachedFile;
    }, () => {
        this.onError();
    });
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Figured the issue. I was supposed to set the value returned my domSanitizer to the src

```
this.src = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(cachedFile));
```